# sample code for collision detection in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can you please suggest sample code for collision detection of two imageviews.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You can Detect Collision between two images by making rect for those image views.

Consider my image-views being named: `img_view1` and `img_view2`.

Image-views creation:

```
//For img_view1 rect
//parameters are x,y,width,height
CGRect image_rect1 = CGRectMake(img_view1.position.x,img_view1.position.y,100,100);

//For img_view2 rect
//parameters are x,y,width,height
CGRect image_rect2 = CGRectMake(img_view2.position.x,img_view2.position.y,100,100);
```

Collision detection:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(image_rect1, image_rect2))
{
    NSLog(@"Rect is Intersecting");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nice answere @Anish, however you dont really need to create a new `CGRect` for the views as you can simply use their respective `frame` properties.

If you want to put that logic in a method it would look like this:

```
-(BOOL)viewsDoCollide:(UIView *)view1 :(UIView *)view2{
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Simply pass the two views you want to test into this method, and check the output result.