# How to check line intersect in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I want to check line intersect in this demo example.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/android-pattern-lock-on-iphone

In this example I want to check when line intersect and show the alert everytime when line intersect.

But I am unable to do this yet.

Any Idea or suggestions from experts would be highly welcome.

Comment: try CGRectIntersectRect(rect1, rect2) function, which returns you the boolean result of when collision occurs between two objects.

Comment: Sir I am new and I dont know how to use this. can you please teach me and guide me how to use this? I want to learn.

Comment: Check my answer which may help you...

Comment: @NishaSingh: You cannot expect that someone downloads a 3rd party project just to understand your question. You should show the relevant code and explain your problem.

Comment: Sir is there any demo example or tutorials to connect dots with line and if line intersect something will happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2)) 
{
   //alert which you want to show when intersection occurs.
}
```

`rect1` -> The first rectangle to examine.

`rect2` -> The second rectangle to examine.

returns `true` if the two specified rectangles `intersect`; otherwise, `false`. The first rectangle intersects the second if the intersection of the rectangles is not equal to the null rectangle.

Comment: As I understand it, the question was about the intersection of *lines*, not *rectangles*.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in to this question, you might find it helpful.

[sample code for collision detection in iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620510/sample-code-for-collision-detection-in-iphone-sdk/5620767#5620767)

If you check CGGeometry reference at

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

You will find that `CGRectIntersectsRect` expects 2 parameters `CGRect` which is rect1
and `CGRect` which is rect2.

Comment: sir in this demo https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/android-pattern-lock-on-iphone how to check this if(CGRectIntersectsRect(from, pt))
    {
        NSLog(@"Rect is Intersecting");
    }                                                                                                                                    What I pass as an argument to check the line intersect?

Comment: As I understand it, the question was about the intersection of *lines*, not *rectangles*.