# compare two CCSprite

Tags: ios

```
_ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 52)];
        _ball.position = ccp(300, 300);
        [self addChild:_ball];
_ball1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 52)];
        _ball1.position = ccp(300, 300);
        [self addChild:_ball1];


if (_ball1.position.x == _ball.position.x && _ball1.position.y == _ball.position.y) {
        NSLog(@"Stop");
    }
```

if _ball is touch _ball1 not worrking
in this something wrong?

Comment: You should look into `CGRectIntersectsRect` see 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620510/sample-code-for-collision-detection-in-iphone-sdk/5620767#5620767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CGRectIntersectsRect`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) to determine if the sprites overlap:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([_ball1 boundingBox], [_ball2 boundingBox])) {
    NSLog(@"Stop");
}
```

Of course, this is just a rectangular intersection, which is probably unsuitable for circular objects, in which you can use the ideas presented in this [webpage](http://www.71squared.com/en/article/665/collision-detection-methods).

Comment: @ChiragDj Cheers; fixed.

Comment: Actually, this won't do. If the two objects have different anchor points set, this logic would break. `position` doesn't define a clear point within the sprite. Please just use the `boundingBox` property directly inside the intersect comparison, and it will take care of transformations and anchorpoint adjustments.

Comment: @Mazyod OK, like that?

Comment: Yes, that should work for all cases, and is more "cocos2dic".